# How can I loop through lines of a file and find files matching each line?

Tags: shell, text-processing, find, wildcards

In a BASH shell, I would like to take the lines of a file (eg *pattern.txt*) and find the files on my system whose names contain the patterns in each line of my file. So, I have the following for loop

```
for pp in `cat pattern.txt`; do find ./ -iname "*${pp}*" -print0; done
```

which doesn't find any files when if the first line in *pattern.txt* doe exist. So how can I fix the above command line?

Note: Each line in my file contains characters [a-zA-Z] only.

Comment: do the lines in pattern.txt contain wildcards? It would help if you listed a few lines

Comment: @SiegeX The lines in my file do not contain wildcards.

Comment: Could `pattern.txt` be a DOS/Windows text file, which to unix tools looks like each line ends with a CR character? If so, this command would look for files with a CR in their name. Run `cat -A pattern.txt` to check that it does indeed contain only letters (you should see lines like `foobar$`, nor `foobar^M$`).

Comment: @Gilles: the file is indeed formatted DOS/Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r pp; do
  find . -iname "*${pp}*" -print0
done < /path/to/pattern.txt
```

Not sure why you want `-print0`, but I left it in anyway.  Perhaps you are attempting to pipe this to `xargs`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the find command still doesn't find anything.

Comment: Yes at the end I will pipe the results to xargs to copy the files it finds.

Comment: thanks for the comment along with @Gilles observation I got it to work.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a safe and Windows-proof way of looking for a bunch of file name patterns retrieved from a file. The approach I've chosen is to process the list of patterns into a `find` expression.

```
find_expression=$(<pattern \
    sed -e 's/^/-o\n-iname\n*/' \
        -e 's/\r\?$/*/' |            # turn each pattern into -o -iname *foo*
    tail -n +2)                      # remove spurious initial -o
set -f                               # turn off globbing
IFS='
'                                    # split only at newlines
find . \( $find_expression \) -print0
set +f; unset IFS                    # restore defaults
```

Comment: @Gilles... Some people like crossword puzzles. I like trying to work out your scripts :) I think I'm starting to recognize *your* pattern :) ... you are allowing a single invocation of `find` to handle the umpteen (maybe thousands) of args, versus calling `find` unpteen times... The IFS pulls the multi-line output back to a string of args in the form: `-iname *abc*`, each seperated by `-o` (which I assume means "or")... Howerver I am a bit puzzled by `\( \)`.. are they a feature of the shell to group the args, or are they a specific requirement of `find`?...(the puzzle is *almost* solved.. :)

Comment: @fred.bear: `\(` and `\)` are passed to `find` as `(` and `)` respectively; the only shell feature used there is the backslash to quote the next character (so that the parentheses are not interpreted as such by the shell). The rest is `find` expression syntax: `(` and `)` for expression grouping, `-o` as the binary “or” operator.

Answer (score 2):

The answer @SiegeX presents will work, but if you have a lot of files in your pattern file, this might become slow and clumsy. You might get much better performance by using a different tool, like this:

```
find . | grep -f pattern.txt
```

Yup, that was the whole thing.